# Динамическое выполнение кода находящегося в строке

Tags: c#

Здраствуйте, можно ли сделать так, чтоб стринг, например, `string text="if(a>0) {a+b}";` программа поняла как простой код. Есть ли какой-то API для этого?

Comment: Могу поспорить, вам это на самом деле не нужно. Расскажите, какую настоящую задачу вы решаете.

Comment: @TigranVoskanyan, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: есть CSharpCodeProvider, пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477349/196972)

Answer (score 11):

Как таковой в языке такой возможности нет - это небезопасно и в общем-то не нужно. Если дать пользователю выполнять произвольный код, введенный в виде обычной строки, это может привести к различным нерриятным и нежелательным последствиям. Однако разработчики C# уже не первый день пилят проект под названием Roslyn (пару слов о нем можете прочесть [тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Roslyn) и [здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/130903/))
Этот проект позволит получить доступ к компилятору, и позволяте выполнять задачи вроде вашей. Помимо этого есть и опенсорсные решения, например [вот этот проект](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso/)
Маленький пример со страницы этого пректа:

```
var interpreter = new Interpreter();
var result = interpreter.Eval("8 / 2 + 2");
```

Думаю, то, что вам нужно. 
При желании можно написать свой велосипед - в рамках институтских курсов по программированию есть ряд посвященных этому дисциплин. Впрочем, если делать это не через одно место, то это довольно трудоемкий, хотя и интересный, процесс, требующий изучения довольно обширного спектра литературы