# Перевсти код из Python в C#

Tags: python, c#, c#-7.3

Есть ли в C# аналог `eval` из Python? Например, я хотел бы сделать на C# аналог следующего кода на Python:

```
print("результат: ", eval(input("Введите: ")))
```

Comment: Не думаю, что у вас с print или input возникли проблемы, так что лучше перефразировать как "есть ли аналог eval в c#"

Comment: В c# выполнить подобие `eval` довольно сложно и в таком варианте это не получится.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/319037/373567

Comment: [IronPython](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IronPython)?

Answer (score 2):

Для начала необходимо подключить nuget пакет Roslyn: microsoft.codeanalysis.csharp.scripting
Далее код:

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.WithOptimizationLevel(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.OptimizationLevel.Debug);
Console.Write("Введите: ");
string input = Console.ReadLine();
var script = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting.CSharpScript.Create(input, options: options, globalsType: null);
var runner = script.CreateDelegate();
object output = runner.Invoke().Result;
Console.WriteLine("результат: "+output);
```

Решение довольно медленно работает при компиляции, но если откомпилить и  держать в памяти - будет работать быстро.